# RecyclerView not counting above 10

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My `RecyclerView` does not count above 10 items. After the 10th item, it shows item 9 again and then item 1 and 2.

This `RecyclerView` produces the bug:

```
mViewModel.getmPremixableIngredientsLive().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<Ingredient>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<Ingredient> premixableIngredients) {
                ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter premixableComponentsRecyclerViewAdpater = new ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter(premixableIngredients);
                mBinding.premixableIngredientsRecyclerview.setAdapter(premixableComponentsRecyclerViewAdpater);
                GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
                mBinding.premixableIngredientsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            }
        });
```

This is the code of my `adapter`:

```
public class ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Ingredient> mIngredients;

    private IngredientRecyclerViewItemBinding mBinding;

    public ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        mIngredients = ingredients;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.ingredient_recycler_view_item,
                parent,
                false
        );
        return new ViewHolder(mBinding.getRoot());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShowIngredientsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mBinding.position.setText((position + 1) + ".");
        mBinding.componentName.setText(mIngredients.get(position).getmComponent().getmName());
        mBinding.amount.setText((mIngredients.get(position).getGrammPerCow() / 1000) + "kg/cow");
        mBinding.dragBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mIngredients.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

xml layout for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_recyclerview_item_linearLayout"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/component_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Component 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="50kg"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/drag_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drag_grey"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: can you share the xml code for ingredient_recycler_view_item please?

Comment: Also, Two maybe unrelated questions:1-why not use a LinearLayout instead of a GridLayout with only 1 column ( or row)? 2- what is dragbtn that you are hiding in every single ItemView in code?

Comment: I added the xml code 
1.) Actually this has no specific reason, I think I can change it
2.) The drag btn is used in a more complex adapter in the edit fragment to realize drag and drop. In that adapter everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not implementing databinding correctly in your recyclerview. You shouldn't declare mBinding as a global variable in the adapter. Instead, it should be a global variable in the custom viewholder class. I share an example recyclerview adapter code with databinding below. You can adapt it to your case. Notice that binding is not a global variable in the adapter, but in the custom viewholder. And the viewholder accept binding as argument, so we pass binding instance to the viewholder when we create the viewholder and we use that instance when onBindViewHolder is called.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

private final List<Product> mProductList;
private final ProductItemClickListener mListener;

ProductAdapter(@NonNull List<Product> productList, ProductItemClickListener listener) {
    mProductList =productList;
    mListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ItemProductBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_product,
                    parent, false);

    return new ProductViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(mProductList.get(position), mListener);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    final ItemProductBinding binding;

    ProductViewHolder(ItemProductBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    void bind(Product currentProduct, ProductItemClickListener clickListener){
        //For each item, corresponding product object is passed to the binding
        binding.setProduct(currentProduct);
        binding.setProductItemClick(clickListener);
        //This is to force bindings to execute right away
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}

public interface ProductItemClickListener {
    void onProductItemClicked(Product product);
}
}
```